# Java Scanner HasNext() .next()

Tags: java, scanner

В задачах ( Maven project с autoTest ) часто ставиться задание на приём и обработку введённых с клавиатуры последовательности чисел. Количество и знак чисел разные каждый раз.
Типа :
1.) - 576 -484 444 0 257 23 ;
2.) 2 9 5 0 13 7 ;
Вариант :

```
while (input.HasNextInt()){
  if(input.next() != null) { ... }
  else{ break;}
}
```

В Eclipse, к примеру, почему-то не срабатывает. Т.е. после нажатия клавиши Enter программа продолжает ожидать ввода.
В случае :

```
while (input.HasNextInt()){
  if(input.next()) { ... }
  else{ break;}
}
```

Пишет, что не может конвертировать String в Boolean.
Ну и сам Eclipse почему-то при запуске Maven  не считывает ввод, а запускает тесты и тесты проходит без ошибок

Comment: Есть же разница между `if(input.next() != null)` и `if(input.next())` :) `next` возвращает строку https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()

Comment: Т.е.  { Has.next() } вполне достаточно ? Когда закончятся все введённые цифры он сам остановит цикл ? Я имел дело с интерпретируемыми языками. И там интерпретатор сам выполнял проверку на пустоту = null. А как это в Java можно реализовать ? Я, проверил next(). Т.е. Я спарсил в boolean. Но парсер обработал как false всё что выдавалось. НО даже вариант if ( ! Boolean.getBoolean(input.next())){} несработал

Comment: Думаю, тут лучше разъяснят https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/klass-scanner :)

Comment: { Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
          
               List<Integer> val = new ArrayList<>();
               while (input.hasNext()){                
             
                       int number= input.nextInt();
                       val.add(number);
              
               input.close();
           
     // -574 -484 444 -217 978 -370 269 -9 189 } Программа ожидает дальнейшего ввода. При выводе ввода - выводит, НО опять же, работать не прекращает, т.е. можно и дальше повторить ввод и она опять выведет. А мне нужно загнать ввод в динамический список.